# Entity Framework "Joins" resulting in returning entire table from SQL

Tags: linq, entity-framework

We are writing entity lambda expression query like this. But when we checked in profile. There were almost all the tables which were used in join returning entire table to the .net linq queries.

We have few transaction tables which has thousands of records. which is causing performance issue. 
Please let us know if we can avoid table returning entire rows to .net

```
var result = (from f in f
    join a in this.Context.a on f.primeryKey equals a.primeryKey
    join d in this.Context.d on f.secondid equals d.secondid
    join t in this.Context.t on d.thirdId equals t.thirdId
    where t.isfoo && pfIds.Contains(a.fourthId.HasValue ? a.fourthId.Value : -1)
    select f).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Please post the generated query.

Answer (score 0):

Well, no real answer, for that I don't have enough info, but a few remarks to improve your query.

First remark: Don't do `Contains` and `HasValue`, because Linq won't SQL-ize these operations. I'm also not quite sure about the this.Context. stuff.

Second: NULL won't join in smart joins.

Third: Instead of selecting `f`, you'd typically select only a few fields of `f` that you need.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to rewrite your query. EF really needs to get all lines to utilize operator ? in order to evaluate value in a.fourthId column. I believe that

```
var result = (from f in f
    join a in this.Context.a on f.primeryKey equals a.primeryKey
    join d in this.Context.d on f.secondid equals d.secondid
    join t in this.Context.t on d.thirdId equals t.thirdId
    where t.isfoo && pfIds.Contains(a.fourthId)
    select f).Distinct().ToList();
```

would meet your needs without necessary overhead, that evaluation seems to be superfluous.